# jquery css load problem with FF/chrome on GAE server

Tags: google-app-engine, jquery-ui

i'm using jqueryUI 1.4.3 datepicker in my GAE app. It works fine on localhost server with IE/FF/Chrome. But after i updated it to GAE server http://liverpooltalks.appspot.com/, it only works with IE. i assume the css isn't loaded correctly. Can someone help me out?

Comment: Can you elaborate on what is the issue you are having on non IE browsers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay，i figured it out. it's caused by the configuration in app.yaml which looks like

handlers:

1. url: /statics/css   static_dir:
   statics/css   mime_type: text/css
2. url: /statics/js
   static_dir: statics/js
   mime_type: text/javascript
3. url: /statics/images
   static_dir: statics/images
   mime_type: image/png
4. url: .*
   script: main.py

I put the whole folder of JqueryUI under /statics/js, so the css files were transferred with MIME type text/plain. I moved JqueryUI css files to /statics/css. The issue is gone.

Answer (score 1):

The calendar works but non-IE browsers aren't picking up the CSS for any of the jQuery-UI stuff. If you look at `/statics/js/JqueryUI/themes/base/jquery.ui.all.css` you'll see that it just does `@import` to pull in some more stylesheets (and those do the same). You could be having absolute versus relative path issues, try adding full paths:

```
@import url("/statics/js/JqueryUI/themes/base/jquery.ui.base.css");
@import url("/statics/js/JqueryUI/themes/base/jquery.ui.theme.css");
```

And similarly inside all the imported stylesheets.

Different browsers often interpret relative paths differently so absolute paths are generally best.

You should be able to get a single jQuery-UI stylesheet out of the theme roller, just one stylesheet should serve you better anyway.